# Replace empty alt tag on <img> tag

Tags: php, image, preg-match-all

I would like to replace my empty alt tags on images in a string. I have a string that contains all the text for a curtain page. In the text are also images, and a lot of them have empty tags (old data), but most of the time they do have title tags. 
For example: 
`<img src="assets/img/test.png" alt="" title="I'am a title tag" width="100" height="100" />`

What I wish to have: 
`<img src="assets/img/test.png" alt="" title="I'am a title tag" alt="I'am a title tag" width="100" height="100" />`

So:
I need to find all the images in my string, loop trough the images, find title tags, find alt tags, and replace the empty alt tags with the title tags that do have a value.

This is what i tried:

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$return, $text);
if(isset($text)) {
            foreach( $text as $itemImg ) {
                foreach( $itemImg as $item ) {
                    $array = array();
                    preg_match( '/title="([^"]*)"/i', $item, $array );
                    if(isset($array[1])) {
                        //So $array[1] is a title tag, now what?
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

I don't know have to complete the code, and I think there must be a easier fix for this. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Regex` is not a good approach you should use `DOMDocument` for parsing `HTML`. Here we are querying on those elements whose `alt` attribute is empty which is actually asked in question.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/813335)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$string=<<<HTML
<img src="assets/img/test1.png" alt="" title="I'am a title tag" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="assets/img/test2.png" alt="" title="I'am a title tag" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="assets/img/test3.png" alt="" title="I'am a title tag" width="100" height="100" /> 
HTML;

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($string,LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);
$results = $domXPath->query('//img[@alt=""]');
foreach($results as $result)
{
    $title=$result->getAttribute("title");
    $result->setAttribute("alt",$title);
    echo $domDocument->saveHTML($result);
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe you could use Javascript for this kind of things with jquery
like:

```
$('img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('alt', $(this).attr('title'));
});
```

hope it helps

Regards.

Comment: It didn't sound like the OP wanted to modify this in runtime on the browser, but rather update the HTML source files that already exist.

Answer (score 2):

What you want here is an HTML parser library that can manipulate HTML and then save it again. By using regular expressions to modify HTML markup, you're setting yourself up for a mess.

The DOM module built into PHP offers this functionality: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Here's an example (cribbed from [this article](http://htmlparsing.com/php.html)):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
        $image->setAttribute('src', 'http://example.com/' . $image->getAttribute('src'));
}
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: this is also the way, if in PHP!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DOMDocument` to achieve your requirement. Below is one of the sample code for your reference:

```
<?php
$html = '<a href="http://example.com" rel="nofollow external">test</a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//a[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@rel), ' '), ' external ')]");
foreach($nodes as $node) {
    $node->setAttribute('href', 'http://example.org');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it below:

```
function img_title_in_alt($full_img_tag){

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($full_img_tag);
    $imageTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach($imageTags as $tag) {

        if($tag->getAttribute('src')!==''){
            return '<img src="'.$tag->getAttribute('src').'" width="'.$tag->getAttribute('width').'" height="'.$tag->getAttribute('height').'" alt="'.$tag->getAttribute('title').'" title="'.$tag->getAttribute('title').'" />';
        }
    }
}
```

Now call the function with your full html tag of image. See the example:

```
$image = '<img src="assets/img/test.png" alt="" title="I\'am a title tag" width="100" height="100" />';

print img_title_in_alt($image);
```